# Птицы оригами или оригами птицы?

Tags: untagged

«... на крыльях птиц оригами» или «оригами птиц». Думаю, вообще без дефиса....

Answer (score 3):

В словарь загляните:

**ОРИГАМИ**, неизм.; ср. [от япон. ori - сгиб, складка и kami - бумага]. Искусство изготовления декоративных изделий из бумаги путём сгибания её в различных направлениях (возникло в Японии). Ребёнок занимается в кружке оригами. // **Изделие, изготовленное таким способом. Собачка-оригами.**

Поэтому правильно: ***на крыльях птиц-оригами***.

Приложение в постпозиции отделяется дефисом.

Answer (score 2):

*Оба* варианта неправильны. "*Крылья птиц оригами*" означало бы, что ссылаются на "*птицу оригами*" как биологический вид. "*Крылья оригами птицы*" означало бы принадлежность крыльев не птице, а оригами ("оригами с крыльями"). При этом сочетание "оригами птицы" не может трактоваться как ***птица** (сделанная) **в виде оригами*** (это именно то, что имеется в виду), поскольку "оригами" - существительное (не имеет грамматических признаков прилагательного). Можно предложить два беспредложных варианта:

> - **крылья оригамических птиц** (прилагательное широко употребляется, хотя в словарях мне не попадалось)
> - **крылья оригами-птиц** (крылья принадлежат *птице*, а дефисное словообразование позволяет придать ей свойства, заложенные в первом
>   существительном).